# GDB: set watchpoint into array, defining value size

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

My program uses a `char heap[]` array as a representation of a heap, and it may contain values of different sizes. Most notably for this question, the value at `(uint16_t*) &heap[0]` and `(uint16_t*) &heap[2]` are two 16-bit values.

I wish to set a watchpoint on the second of these values, and break when it reaches a certain value. In this case the second value is a counter that is counting down, and I wish to break when it reaches e.g zero (but for my testing purposes currently, I use `9998`).

This is what my C-program looks like (Put it in `test.c` and compile with `gcc -g -o mainh test.c`)

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEAP_SIZE 65536
char heap[HEAP_SIZE];
void proc0();
void proc1();
void proc0()
{ }
void proc1()
{ }
void main()
{
    *(uint16_t *) &heap[0] = (uint16_t) 4;
    proc0();
    exit(0);
}
```

My framework generates a GDB file to install some breakpoints and modify these two values, and GDB accepts them without problem. The problem I experience is that **the watchpoint that is installed first is never executed**. (Put the below commands in `commandsh.txt`)

```
watch *(uint16_t*) &heap[2]
cond 1 *(uint16_t*) &heap[2] == 9998
commands
set *(uint16_t*) &heap[0] = 50
p *(uint16_t*) &heap[0]
continue
end

break proc0
commands
set *(uint16_t*) &heap[2] = (*(uint16_t*) &heap[2]) - 1
c
end

run
q
```

Breakpoints are installed at `main`,`exit` and `proc0`, but only the `proc0` one is relevant for the problem I have, so the rest are omitted. The `proc0` breakpoint correctly fires and decrements the value at `(uint16_t *) &heap[2]` to `9998` from an initial `9999`. However, the watchpoint and its condition never triggers, leaving the first value as an unchanged `4`, whereas I expect it to be `50`. (Execute commands by running `gdb -q -x commandsh.txt mainh` from bash)

My output when I run GDB shows that the watchpoint never breaks, and the value at the indicated heap address is not printed:

```bash
Reading symbols from mainh...
Hardware watchpoint 1: *(uint16_t*) &heap[2]
Breakpoint 2 at 0x1151: file test.c, line 8.

This GDB supports auto-downloading debuginfo from the following URLs:
https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com 
Enable debuginfod for this session? (y or [n]) [answered N; input not from terminal]
Debuginfod has been disabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled off' to .gdbinit.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 2, proc0 () at test.c:8
8   { }
[Inferior 1 (process 146113) exited normally]
```

I suspected the problem was related to my syntax, and tried to change the watchpoint to

```
watch {uint16_t} &heap[2]
cond 1 {uint16_t} &heap[2] == 9998
commands
set {uint16_t} &heap[0] = 50
continue
end
```

but that changed nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provided [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @tom Thank you, I made it smaller. Do you want to help me now?

Comment: I want to help you, but I can't get a executive program so that I can't find problem.

Comment: @tom It runs now, i left instructions for you. Now you can help me.

Comment: OK, please wait a moment.

Comment: Given `char heap[];`, code like `(uint16_t*) &heap[0]` is undefined behavior.  It's always a strict aliasing violation and if `heap` is not properly aligned for a `uint16_t`, it's also undefined behavior for that reason.

Comment: * &heap[0] == heap[0], and value of them is equal to value of heap. Why you use *`(uint16_t *) &heap[0]`? For what?  And `heap[0]` is type of `char`, `&heap[0]` is type of `char*`, convert `char*` to `(uint16_t*)` for what?

Comment: Why not directly use `heap[0] = 4`?

Comment: **Correct:** `*(&heap[0]) == heap[0]`, why you use `*(uint16_t *) &heap[0]`? For what? And `heap[0]` is type of `char`, `&heap[0]` is type of `char*`, convert `char*` to `(uint16_t*)` for what? Why not directly use `heap[0] = 4` to replace `*(uint16_t *) &heap[0] = (uint16_t) 4;` ?

Comment: @tom as I said, my program uses its own allocator. I have an array that I allocate differently sized values from. It is valid to grab the address of a cell in the heap, and view it as a pointer to a larger structure. I make sure that it is aligned etc. I need higher precision that a `char` can give, so I've allocated two bytes from this array.

Comment: @lundin this is completely unrelated to my problem, and not relevant.

Comment: @Robert Given that the line `*(uint16_t *) &heap[0] = (uint16_t) 4;` has no defined behavior in the C language, I fail to see how it isn't related.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a watchpoint only triggers if the watched expression changes in the program, and not if you change them in gdb.

Comment: @ssbssa this was absolutely a problem, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Can you see if `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0` will make things work?  (It did for me, with GDB 13.1 on Ubuntu 23.04). Your program will run slowly because GDB will implement the watchpoint by single-stepping execution, evaluating the expression after each instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the hardware watchpoints work when the *program being debugged* changes the value.

They *don't* work when it's not the program, but GDB itself is performing the change (as is happening here).

There are other similar instances of "missed watchpoints", when e.g. the kernel writes to memory:

```
int fd = open("/dev/zero", ...);
char buf = 'a';               // set a watchpoint on location of buf
read(fd, &buf, 1);            // buf is now changed, but watchpoint doesn't "fire".
```